# Using Linux __init functions during runtime

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

I am in need of calling a certain Linux function from my userland program. I've decided to use custom syscall in order to call needed kernel function. However, said function has __init meaning it gets cleared out of memory after booting. Due to that I keep getting "Bad RIP" kernel panic when invoking my syscall. I have tried manually removing __init but said function has plenty of helper functions that are also __init. I was wondering is there some way to ask kernel not to clear out __init functions?

Comment: Can you post the code and panic/oops output? Chances are some of the __init code is used only once and should be freed; refactoring the code may resolve a panic.

Comment: If you "need" to do this then you are either 1) trying to have fun hacking around the kernel code; 2) using the wrong approach to solve whatever else is your problem. I hope it's 1 and not 2 :P

Comment: @Milag There isn't really much code to show from my side, I do understand __init is only used once and then freed. I am wondering is there a way for kernel to not free up __init function (think of disregarding __init) as I am trying to call such function from runtime in userland.

Comment: Maybe it will work to just change the definition of `__init` & friends [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9.1/source/include/linux/init.h#L50).